# Is AI good at detecting AI-generated content?

Tags: image-generation, deepfakes, video-classification

Are AI models good at detecting AI-generated image or video content like deep fakes? Which model can we use for the detection of AI-generated image content?

Comment: depends... if you can discriminate, you can improve using that discriminator, check "GANs", that's literally how they work